# NGINX - rewrite and error 404

Tags: nginx, configuration, url-rewriting, nginx-location

my rewrite works.

On the other hand my 404 error redirection does not work anymore.

If I add to my .php link it returns me there is no file.

Similarly when I put in my link an admin / it puts me the opening, the menu and the copiryght.

Example if I put https://mon.domain.com/admin/ it loads me a page while I would like my 404 error page.

What I would like, if the pages does not exist that in any case I come across my error 404

Can you help me?

Here is the configuration of nginx:

```
upstream www {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}

server {
    listen 80 default;
    server_name no-impact.eu;
        return 301 https://my.domain.com;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name my.domain.com;

    fastcgi_param HTTPS on;
    ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my.domain.com/privkey.pem;
        ssl_session_timeout  5m;
        ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
        ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
        ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    root /var/www/my.domain.com/;
    index index.php;

    error_page 400 401 402 403 404 500 502 503 504 /error.html;

    location /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        root /var/www/letsencrypt;
    }

    location = /error.html {
        root  /var/www/my.domain.com/error/;
        index index.html;
    }

    location / {
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ @rewrite;
    }

    location @rewrite {
        rewrite ^/([\w-]+)-page-(\d+)$ /index.php?id=$1&page=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/([\w-]+)-(\d+)$ /index.php?id=$1&id_tutoriel=$2 last;
        rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?id=$1 last;
    }


    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

}
```

Comment: Try moving `root /var/www/my.domain.com/;` into the `location / {...}` block within the server block.

Comment: I just try, but it puts me the error everywhere on the pages that works

Answer (score -1):

The problem here is that your rewrite tells nginx to redirect everything to the backend, so nginx does not detect a 404 by itself. Your backend then handles the request and sends a 404, which nginx sends back directly to the client.

In order for nginx to intercept the 404 and show its own error page, you need to add the directive `fastcgi_intercept_errors on;` to your `.php`-location.

Comment: Thanks all for your help, i have solved this issue. The error was in the third regular expression of the block `location / {}` the `(.*)` replaced all characters whose this /. I have replaced my expression by `([\w-]+)` ant it's work.